# How do I differenciate identical USB devices connected to the same USB hub?

Tags: usb

`lsusb -v` shows the same information for both devices (except of ever growing device number when reconnecting device)
All the attributes of the devices are identical, so it's not possible to differenciate them by sort of uuid.
How do I differenciate these identical USB devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lsusb -t`, which prints the physical tree, it gets its information by parsing `/proc/bus/usb/devices`. see the [Documentation/usb/proc_usb_info.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/usb/proc_usb_info.txt#L114) file for information on the format, if you're going to parse it yourself, but basically each `T:` line gives you the parent device id and port on same